# How to SUM all values of a Filter with a relative end range

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula

How can I SUM the totals (cell below) of each column titled "$ Balance" between the ranges of C1-HD2?

• The column at the end of the range, HD, needs to be flexible for column additions/removals.

It's possible that HLOOKUP isn't even the right function... I haven't found a way to SUM the HLOOKUP function... which only appears to return a specified cell, (e.g. where E1 is "$Balance"):

```
=HLOOKUP($E$1, $C$1:HD$2, 2, FALSE)
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER($C2:HD2; $C$1:HD$1="$ Balance"))
```

or:

```
=SUM(FILTER(
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, 3)&":"&ADDRESS(2, COLUMN()-1)), 
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, 3)&":"&ADDRESS(1, COLUMN()-1))="$ Balance"))
```

if you want to drag down the 2nd formula change two `2` for `ROW(A2)`

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you, works flawlessly! :)

Comment: Update: I first tested on a cell elsewhere, but my Total Balance cell is also on Row 2 and now it is telling me a Circular Dependency was detected...? Any idea?

Comment: See this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/RmPd060.png

Comment: @WebMW try: `=SUM(FILTER(C2:HD2; C1:HD1="$ Balance"))`

Comment: This range works, but how can I adjust it to work on all rows? Also, the column at the end of the range, HD, needs to be flexible for column additions/removals.... so if I add 10 columns before HD1, the "end range" needs to change?? =SUM(FILTER($C2:HD2, $C$1:HD$1="$ Balance")) ??? I think this seems to be working for both rows and columns! Does it look right to you?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet? as for the range... if you add 10 columns before HD eg. between HC and HD then the range in the formula will change as you would expect. however if you add 10 columns after HD eg between HD and HE - then the range wont update.

Comment: Thanks player0, I believe I got it working... (updated my last comment). Appreciate your help! If you could please update your answer, I can mark you as the accepted answer. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I added one more alternative where you can notice `COLUMN()-1` which tells formula to create range always on the left side eg. it doesnt matter where you insert more columns. the range will be deduced alway from the left of the cell which holds the formula

Comment: That is great and will be helpful to others. Could you update your first solution to include the proper absolute referencing on the cells? This correct range will work for all rows and allow the "end range" to shift if columns are added before HD: `=SUM(FILTER($C2:HD2, $C$1:HD$1="$ Balance"))`